# csv module broken for comma as delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I am using python's `csv` module and using quotes to contain the field that contains the separator.

The file `a.txt` looks like the following:

```
ab, ",cd"
```

And i get the following that indicates that it did not escape the comma in double quotes.

```
In [27]: with open('a.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    ...:     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         if row:
    ...:             print(row)
    ...:
['ab', ' "', 'cd"']
```

Comment: The space is throwing off the csv module's parsing. With `ab,",cd"` it works as expected. What's producing this bunk csv data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not broken, it's the expected behaviour.

What happens is that the csv module only considers the quote as a quote if it's *right after the separator*.

If there's something before that (space or something else), the quote is considered like being part of the data.

[zvone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106338/6451573) explains how to workaround that (in the case of a space only)

Answer (score 3):

As @wim pointed out in a comment, this is caused by the space character after the comma.

If you configure the reader to skip the space after the delimiter, then it will work:

```
>>> print(list(csv.reader(io.StringIO('ab, ",cd"'), skipinitialspace=True)))
[['ab', ',cd']]
```

BTW, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) for other CSV reader options.

Comment: What happens is that the csv module considers the quote _right after the separator_.

If there's something before that (space or something else), the quote is considered like being part of the data. your answer allows to fix this